# How get class by name with generic or how correct realize this problem?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to dynamically load catalogs to DevExpress grid and repositories. Some columns reference to other tables. I want to realize without "if-else, switch" methods, solve with generic for example.

My project uses Entity Framework and the Unit-of-work pattern etc.

```
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit repositoryItemLookUpEdit = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit()
{
  ValueMember = repositoryItem.ValueMember,
  DisplayMember = repositoryItem.DisplayMember
;

// var objectType = GetTypeByName(repositoryItem.FinalTable);
if (repositoryItem.FinalTable=="DeviceTypes")
{
    objectList = GetObjectList<DeviceTypes>();
}
else if (repositoryItem.FinalTable == "DeviceKinds")
{
    objectList = GetObjectList<DeviceKinds>();
}

repositoryItemLookUpEdit.DataSource = objectList;
bandedGridColumn.ColumnEdit = repositoryItemLookUpEdit;

---

private IEnumerable<T> GetObjectList <T>() where T : Entity
{
    IEnumerable<T> objectList=Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)))
    {
        objectList = unitOfWork.GetRepository<T>().GetAll();
    }

    return objectList;
}

---

private T GetTypeByName<T>(string typeName) where T:Entity
{
   foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Reverse())
   {
      var type = assembly.GetType(typeName);

      if (type != null)
      {
         return type as T;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Either you know the concrete type at compile time then generics work well as you can name the type or you only know them at runtime then you don't have a concrete type but only a descriptive instance of the type class (your GetTypeByName method can return such a type) but then generic don't really work.  Most frameworks have a non-generic version of their methods then taking a Type object as simple parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is here:

```
public List<object> GetTableNyName(string tableName)
    {
                List<object> objectList = new List<object>();
                var entityType = GetTypeOfTable(tableName);
                if (entityType!=null)
                {
                   var query = (IQueryable)_context.GetType().GetMethod("Set", 1, 
                   Type.EmptyTypes).MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType).Invoke(_context, null);
                   objectList = query.OfType<object>().ToList();   
                }
                return objectList;
    }
            --
   private IEntityType GetTypeOfTable(string tableName)
   {
      var entityType = _context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.ClrType.Name == tableName).FirstOrDefault();
      return entityType;
   }
```